# Why is onClick() function abstract?

Tags: android, interface, onclick, listener, abstract

(WORKING WITH KOTLIN)

I am a bit confused about this topic.

When I implement **View.OnClickListener** interface into my class I called 'Testing', I get the message below:

*Class 'Testing' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onClick(v:View!): Unit defined in android.view.View.OnClickListener.*

I know this can be solved implementing this function **onClick(v: View!)** into my 'Testing' class. But my question is: Why the message says that onClick(v:View!) is abstract?

When I check this function into the 'OnClickListener' of the 'View' class, I can see the function doesn't include the **abstract** keyword as we can see in this code:

```
/**
 * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a view is clicked.
 */
public interface OnClickListener {
    /**
     * Called when a view has been clicked.
     *
     * @param v The view that was clicked.
     */
    void onClick(View v);
}
```

This error message is not happening with **OnCreateContextMenuListener** interface, though. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Why abstract ?

   All methods in an interface is abstract, and they have no method body(implementation).
2. Why OnCreateContextMenuListener is ok.

   What is the super class of your Testing class? I think the super class (or any ancestor class) must has implemented onCreateContextMenu method.

Comment: Hey liuwons! Thank you so much for your answer. Effectively, my class is inheriting from 'AppCompatActivity'. And as you said I checked that onCreateContextMenu is implemented into 'Activity' class. So question solved! ;)